# ConTeXt: Grathwohl's code for book design

Tags: macros, errors, context

I'm trying to understund the problem I have with this code (you can see it at https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb25-1/grathwohl.pdf ):

```
\setupinterlinespace[line=1.35em]
\setupalign[hanging]

\setuphead[chapter][page=yes,before={\blank[force,4*line]},after={\blank[4*line]},command=\mychap]    

\defineexpandable\mychap#1#2%
{\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
\hfill
\setupframed
[offset=0.5em,frame=off]%
\tbox
{\framed
[width=2cm,align=left]
{\ss #1}}%

\tbox
{\framed
[width=.5\textwidth,
align=flushright,
leftframe=on]
{\hyphenpenalty 10000 \ss #2}}%
\egroup}

\def\Drop {\DroppedCaps
{} {Sans} {3\baselineskip}
{2pt} {1\baselineskip} {2}}

\def\chap#1/#2/{\Drop #1{\smallcaps #2}}

\starttext

\chapter{The S\’eance}

\chap O/n a march evening/, at eight

\stoptext
```

I don't know if I'm trying of execute obsolete commands in Mkiv, I'd preciate your help.

Comment: I don't think it is meant to be compilable as is, but it may also be using deprecated stuff.

Comment: I cannot find the error, but it don't compile with the command context. It must have a sintactical error or an obsolete command. I'd like to know which is the case, cause i'd like to make a document whith the intended appearence.

Comment: Is `\DroppedCaps` defined elsewhere? If not, that looks like a problem.

Comment: No, it isn't. Is the first occurrence in the code. I'll see that. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps this is a problem, but it is not the only problem. If I delete the relevant lines, it doesnt compile anyway. I cannot believe how hard is to learn ConTeXt! Beautiful documents, but you find old piecs of code, most manuals are not friendly (at least for someone like me), a lot of pages in Context garden without information or with broken links... But it's wonderful. A pity the mess in documentation.

Comment: May be, to add simplicity, you could define `\def\chap#1#2/{..}`, so you save the need to type the first `/` like `\chap On a march evening/, at eight...`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the tugboat article the `mychap` macro is defined as `\def\mychap#1#2` (I don't know why you changed it to `\defineexpandable\mychap#1#2`, which is wrong syntax). In MkIV, the macro passed to `command` key of `\setuphead` needs to be unexpandable: so either use `\unexpanded\def\mychap#1#2` or `\define[2]\mychap` (as I do below).

In MkII, there were two mechanisms for dropped capitals, `\DroppedCaps` and `\placeinitial`. In MkIV, the dropped capped feature was reimplemented using lua, and only the `\placeinitial` alternative was kept. So, you need to use `\placeinitial` instead of `DroppedCaps`.

If you make these changes, the code compiles. Here is a complete working example. While I was at it, I also cleaned up the code a little.

```
\setupinterlinespace[line=1.35em]
\setupalign[hanging]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [
    page=yes,
    before={\blank[force,4*line]},
    after={\blank[4*line]},
    command=\mychap,
  ]

\defineframed
  [chapterframed]
  [
    offset=0.5em,
    frame=off,
    align={flushright,nothypenated},
    location=top,
    foregroundstyle=sans,
  ]

\define[2]\mychap
  {\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
    \hfill
    \chapterframed[width=2cm]{#1}
    \chapterframed[width=0.5\textwidth, leftframe=on]{#2}
    \egroup}

\def\chap#1/#2/{\placeinitial #1{\sc #2}}

\starttext

\chapter{The Séance}

\chap O/n a march evening/, at eight

\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]