# ConTeXt: Number chapter size - box

Tags: context, size

Few days ago, @Aditya offered a perfect solution to a problem I had posted, writing the following code:

```
 \setupinterlinespace[line=1.35em]
 \setupalign[hanging]

\setuphead
 [chapter]
 [
  page=yes,
  before={\blank[force,4*line]},
  after={\blank[4*line]},
   command=\mychap,
 ]

  \defineframed
[chapterframed]
[
offset=0.5em,
frame=off,
align={flushright,nothypenated},
location=top,
foregroundstyle=sans,
 ]

 \define[2]\mychap
  {\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
  \hfill
  \chapterframed[width=2cm]{#1}
   \chapterframed[width=0.5\textwidth, leftframe=on]{#2}
   \egroup}

   \def\chap#1/#2/{\placeinitial #1{\sc #2}}

    \starttext

   \chapter{The Séance}

    \chap O/n a march evening/, at eight

    \stoptext
```

I believed I could find a way to do two things: 
1) Set the size of the number in title.
2) Set the size of the vertical line (left edge of a frame) as I wish.

I couldn't do neither. I can change the size of the vertical line but always is too long for me. And I could't operate in any way over argument #1 in line \chapterframed[width=2cm]{#1}. I know I'm asking too much, but I really want to learn ConTeXt, so, I appreciate all help in two ways:
a) The solution.
b) The indication about documentation where I can understund the solution. I feel I'm copying codes that sometimes I dont't understund (I have read the questions about ConTeXt documentation but is ueless for me about specific issues like this. I feel lost in a jungle with a lot of paths going nowhere (broken or void links) and deprecated "trees" (commands).)

(Of course, I'll appreciate all help, either in form a) or b). Thanks.

Comment: The referenced question is [ConTeXt: Grathwohl's code for book design](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323673).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what is happening! Compile the document with `\showstruts` and you get the following (the thin vertical lines are the struts; the thick vertical line is from `leftframe=on`)

[image]

By default, `ConTeXt` adds a `\strut` around the section numbers and section titles (and a lot of other places), because the content looks better with the strut. If you don't want that, you can add `struct=no` to the appropriate `\setup...` command.

So, in principle

```
\setuphead[chapter][...., struct=no, ...]
\defineframed[chapterframed][...., struct=no,...]
```

should have worked, but it does not. This is what you get:

[image]

The strts are still there. This is because the command `\mychap` is not calling the helper marco that initializes the head spacing. To do so, simply change the definition of `\mychap` to:

```
\define[2]\mychap
  {\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
   \headsetupspacing% <<<: Added this
   \hfill
   \chapterframed[width=2cm]{#1}
   \chapterframed[width=0.5\textwidth, leftframe=on]{#2}
   \egroup}
```

which gives:

[image]

No more additional struts! Here is the complete code (remove the `\showstruts` when using this)

```
 \setupinterlinespace[line=1.35em]
 \setupalign[hanging]

\setuphead
 [chapter]
 [
  page=yes,
  before={\blank[force,4*line]},
  after={\blank[4*line]},
  command=\mychap,
  strut=no,
 ]

\showstruts

\defineframed
  [chapterframed]
  [
    offset=0em,
    frame=off,
    strut=no,
    align={flushright,nothypenated},
    location=top,
    foregroundstyle=sans,
  ]

\define[2]\mychap
  {\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
   \headsetupspacing
   \hfill
   \chapterframed[width=2cm]{#1}
   \chapterframed[width=0.5\textwidth, leftframe=on]{#2}
   \egroup}

\def\chap#1/#2/{\placeinitial #1{\sc #2}}

\starttext

\chapter{The Séance}

\chap O/n a march evening/, at eight

\stoptext
```

Comment: Wonderful! I could not ever imagine it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

See the annotation in the code for the relevant instructions.  The documentation is in the Garden:

- [`\setuphead`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead)
- [`\setupframed`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupframed) (this is what `\defineframed` inherits).

As a matter of fact, every `\definesomething` command inherits from the corresponding `\setupsomething` command.  For all valid keys of all ConTeXt commands, see the [Commands reference](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/qrcs/setup-en.pdf).

```
\setupinterlinespace[line=1.35em]
\setupalign[hanging]

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [
    page=yes,
    before={\blank[force,4*line]},
    after={\blank[4*line]},
    command=\mychap,
    numberstyle=\tfa, % <- size of number
  ]

\defineframed
  [chapterframed]
  [
    offset=0.2em, % <- influences height of rule
    frame=off,
    align={flushright,nothypenated},
    location=top,
    foregroundstyle=sans,
  ]

\define[2]\mychap
  {\hbox to \hsize \bgroup
    \hfill
    \chapterframed[width=2cm]{#1}
    \chapterframed[width=0.5\textwidth, leftframe=on]{#2}
    \egroup}

\def\chap#1/#2/{\placeinitial #1{\sc #2}}

\starttext

\chapter{The Séance}

\chap O/n a march evening/, at eight

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps I was no clear, I'm sorry, my language is not English. I've tryed reducing offset's value indeed to 0, but the vertical line still is too over and above baseline and topline. And I've tryed to add numberstyle=tfa, with the line  \definebodyfontenvironment [11pt] [a=xpt] (where x is the measure I want, I was trying to find some visually fine), but I could not achieve that the number were bigger than the caps in title. I must have said "set the size in any way I wish". Thank you!

Comment: I think I'm going to give up ConTeXt and return to LaTeX. I looked for a description of \headsetupspacing, Google has 9 pages, none of them describes it, the reference manual doesn't mention it, and Context wiki has no ¡one page! containing the command. It's an impossible task, I don't know how to access to such arcane knowledge. Thank you all, I'm very grateful for the time you dedicated at this problems.

Comment: @Miguel You're welcome.  I documented [`\headsetupspacing`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/headsetupspacing) in the Garden.  If you find other commands which are not documented, please let me know, so I can complete their reference.  I'm also very interested in better documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Henri Menke, you are very kind. I'll continue trying with ConTeXt due yours and others support and cause I know it's a beautiful typesetting system that deserves be better known than it is. I'll make you know if I find myself in a similar situation of not finding some reference.